# Mechanism for the CBS reduction?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I don't get the CBS reduction of ketones in organic chemistry. I can draw two ''chair'' structures for the reduction of phenyl,methyl ketone and each gives a different enantiomer. Both have the phenyl equatorial, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please, help.[image]

Comment: You don't really make the stereochemistry of the oxazaborolidine obvious in either case here. I'm guessing you probably would have to use the opposite enantiomer between to two to get these results. I think the top structure would have the hydrogen dashed back and the bottom would have the H wedged forward.

Comment: Naah, the hydrogen must be cys to boron, but that's how it always is, since when you add BH3 it can only coordinate the nitrogen from above (the bicyclic compund is folded like a book), otherwise it would be too hindered. But I think I found the answer.  I should have used the boat conformation :D Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That may be true, but you didn't add stereochemistry for anything.

Comment: Okay, so in the bottom one, you have the bulky group on the niteogen axial, and in the top one the bulky group is equatorial. So the top answer makes more sense to me, but do you actually know the answer? If so, you might want to answer your own question.